# Java 8 converting a loop which manipulate the elements to a lambda stream

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a for loop which looks like this.

```
for(Customer customer : customers)
{
    Address address = customer.getAdderess();
    String status = address.deliver(parsel);
    customer.setStatus(status);
}
```

Which I want to convert to a lambda stream. The issue is, once the Customer item in the stream is converted (mapped)  to an Address item, the Customer item is no longer available for manipulation.  I have tried something like this.

```
customers.stream()
         .map((customer)-> customer.getAddress())
         .map((address)-> address.deliver())
         .forEach((status)-> customer.setStatus);
```

But it throws a compiler error saying **customer cannot be resolved.**
Is there a way to solve this by using any other stream operators, without introducing much complexity?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why the downvote? question is clear, and an attempt is shown..

Answer (score 2):

```
customers.forEach(customer -> {
     customer.setStatus(customer.getAdderess().deliver(parsel));
});
```

No need to stream; even a simpler for loop, like in your case is not needed.

Comment: Or even simpler, `customers.forEach(customer -> customer.setStatus(customer.getAdderess().deliver(parsel)));`

Comment: But what if I want to run this using parallelStream() ?

Comment: @SufailKhan you can use `customers.parallelStream().forEach(/* rest as above */);`, but it’s unlikely to get a benefit here. You need a large source collection or an expensive operation…

Comment: No need for the braces either ;)